# How to stringtok this long string?

Tags: arduino-uno, string

I have a string,

"id,port,password,ssid,delay,flag,class,category"

Please tell me how can stringtok this and find out the "flag" value(0 or 1)?

Here is what I tried:

```cpp
void setup()
{
    char input[] = {"id,port,password,ssid,delay,flag,class,category"};
    char *ptr;
    Serial.begin(115200);
    ptr = strtok(input, ",");
    Serial.println(ptr);
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        Serial.println(ptr);
    }
}

void loop(){}
```

Comment: I would remove the { and } in `char input[] = {"id,port,password,ssid,delay,flag"};`

Comment: Even with the (useless) braces Juraj suggest removing, your code works as expected. Please, be more specific about what your actual problem is.

Comment: how 'flag' substring separately taken ? what modification that i want to made in program?

Comment: based on position? 6th item?

Answer (score 2):

For strings with a fixed format like that (I assume it's a fixed format...) I normally just do a manual strtok of the whole thing into a set of pointers. No need for a loop.  You can then just test the last one to see if the whole thing tokenised properly, since if anything before that fails then all other subsequent ones will fail and the last one will have failed.

```
void setup()
{
    char input[] = {"id,port,password,ssid,delay,flag,class,category"};
    char *ptr;
    Serial.begin(115200);

    char *id = strtok(input, ",");
    char *port = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *password = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *ssid = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *delay = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *flag = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *class = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *category = strtok(NULL, ",");
    if (category != NULL) { // Everything up to and including category worked
        Serial.print("Flag: ");
        Serial.println(flag);
    }
}

void loop(){}
```

As an aside: if there is ever a chance any of the fields could be empty ("flag,,category" for example) then you should use `strsep()` instead of `strtok()` as I detail in my [tutorial on splitting strings in C](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/splitting-text-c).